# BindMemory migration Swfit 3

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, nsdata

How to migrate this code to Swift 3?

```
let keyBytes = keyData.bytes.bindMemory(to: Void.self, capacity: keyData.count)
```

I'm getting below error

> 'bytes' is unavailable: use withUnsafeBytes instead

Comment: What do you need the pointer for? Some more context would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`keyData` is type of `Data` object and that doesn't have property `bytes`, convert `keyData` to `NSData` and then access `bytes`.

```
let keyBytes = NSData(data: keyData).bytes.bindMemory(to: Void.self, capacity: keyData.count)
```

Comment: OMG, Thank you a lot. May be you know how to fix this: `let cipherText = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>(cipherData.mutableBytes) `. Error _cannot invoke initializer for type unsafemutablepointer<Int8> with an argument list of type (UnsafeMutableRawPointer)_

Comment: @Илья Welcome mate, The error is saying there is no init method for `UnsafeMutablePointer` that takes `UnsafeMutableRawPointer` as argument. Don't know the solution of it may be you need to ask another question on SO.